# Power BI, DAX: Merging multiple rows based on condition and aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I having an requirement from business users and need your help.

From the screenshot, we have BatchNo column, for example the BatchNo HL18002040, business users want to merge Loading Dates into 1 row if they have same BatchNo and then summerizing NetWeight Shipped togother as the Expecting result. I have tried a lot with DAX language but cannot solve the issue.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

The model
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements you can do one of three things:

1. Either hide the `Loading Date` column altogether as suggested by Peter
2. Apply a summarization of the `Loading Date` column (e.g. "Earliest" or "Latest" date, again depending on what makes sense for your use case)
3. Introduce a concatenating measure that gives you all the different dates separated by a defined separator, on one row in the visualization.

Option 1 and 2 should need little explanation, but for option 3 the measure could look like this (EDIT: Updated with more information about your data model):

```
Loading Dates = 
IF (
    ISINSCOPE ( 'Fact_Shipping'[BatchNo] ) , // Blanks measure in total row
    CONCATENATEX (
        Fact_Shipping ,
        -- Format function may not be needed depending on your data model settings and requirements
        FORMAT (  
            RELATED ( DimDate[Date] ) , "yyyy-MM-dd" 
        ) ,
        UNICHAR(10) // Newline character
    )
)
```

You can also use this measure that uses the `Fact_Shipping[DateSK]` column directly, use the performance analyzer in Power BI or benchmarking tool in DAX Studio to see which of these perform better for your use case:

```
Loading Dates 2 = 
IF (
    ISINSCOPE ( 'Fact_Shipping'[BatchNo] ) , // Blanks measure in total row
    CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES ( Fact_Shipping[DateSK] ) ,
        LEFT([DateSK], 4) & "-" & MID([DateSK], 5, 2) & "-" & RIGHT([DateSK], 2) ,
        UNICHAR(10) // Newline character
    )
)
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

Note that your `NetWeight Shipped` column should be summed using a dedicated measure or using the implicit column measure function in Power BI. I recommend adding an explicit measure to do this:

`Total NetWeight Shipped = SUM ( 'Table'[NetWeight Shipped] )`

If you are not using an aggregation on the weight column, the visualization will show multiple rows per `BatchNo`. In the picture above, an implicit column measure is used to summarize the `NetWeight Shipped` column.

Comment: 1. and 2. don't work for me as I want Loading Dates showing and summerized by NetWeight Shipped. For 3. I have appled your DAX but unfortunately each row of BatchNo concats all  the dates of DimDate table. I have to clarify that BatchNo and [NetWeight Shipped] are in Fact table Fact_Shipping and [Loading Date] is the DateBK in DimDate table. These two tables have relationship using DateKey.

Comment: Use the date column in the fact table then? You haven't supplied any information regarding the data model, so it is difficult to fully understand how your model looks. Naturally you can't use the date column of your date table for this.

Comment: The model Fact_Shipping (DateSK) ---> DimDate(DateSK) : [BatchNo] and [NetWeight Shipped] are in Fact_Shippingand and [Loading Date] is also the DateBK in Dim_Date.

Comment: What is the format of `Fact_Shipping[DateSK]`?

Comment: Fact_Shipping[DateSK] is the Surrogate key to link to Dim_Date(DateSK), the format is Whole Number yyyymmdd

Comment: Perfect - I have amended the answer to give you two possible solutions, one that formats `Fact_Shipping[DateSK]` directly and one that fetches the `DimDate[DateBK]` by using `RELATED` from `Fact_Shipping` row context. Hopefully this solves your problem!

Comment: Excellent @Marcus, "Loading Dates 2" works quite well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM(NetWeight Shipped) but remove [Loading Date] from the visual, so that it stops filtering the measure, thereby hindering the aggregation.

Comment: We want to keep [Loading Date]